# Full Support of r.v. and model identification

Tags: econometrics, inference, identifiability

Consider the model: 
$$y_i=x_i'\beta + \epsilon_i$$
where $\epsilon_i$ is i.i.d. and follows a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2>0$ and where the distribution of $x_i$ has full support on $R^k$. You observe a sample of n realizations $(y_i,x_i)$.

Question: Why are all parameters identified and why the full support assumption, meaning that $x_i$ has no constant, is crucial for model identification?

Comment: I haven't fully done the maths so will leave this as a comment but I believe it is because you wouldn't be able to distinguish between $\mu$ and $\beta_0$.    For example  $E(y_i) = \beta_0 + x_i'\beta_1  + \mu$.  Well $\mu$ and $\beta_0$ are both constants and would be conflated so it would be impossible to split the estimate effect of the intercept between them.

Comment: I believe that in this case, there is no $\beta_0$, the key part I am trying to understand is the role of $x_i$ having full support in the model identification!